# Binding to a custom Dependency Property of a UserControl on a Page isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I created a user control, and that has an custom Dependency Property (this property isn't bound in the user control). I am trying to bind that property on the page where I use it. On the application start, the binding is working, but after that I can't update the value.

The value of the binding source is changing and if I bind an object on the page (example the text property of the Text Block) I can see the changes.

Part of my user control:

```
        public int MaxValue
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MaxValueProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MaxValue");
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "MaxValue",
                typeof(int),
                typeof(NumericUpDown),
                new PropertyMetadata(
                    5,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMaxValuePropertyChanged))
                );
```

Part of my Page:

```
<local:NumericUpDown x:Name="NudChapter"
                     Height="40"
                     Width="auto"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     Margin="0,10,0,0"
                     MaxValue="{Binding Path=Model.ChaptersInTheBook}"
                     HintText="Fejezet"/>
```

Comment: does changing `datacontext.Model` notifying about change? same with `model.ChaptersInTheBook`? how you are changing this property and which?

Comment: As a note, you don't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for dependency properties, like `NotifyPropertyChanged("MaxValue")`. Remove that from your UserControl.

Comment: Hi!
The page apply mvvm pattern, the 'ChaptersInTheBook' is in the model of the pages. The page is notified about the changes (I checked that).
How you are changing this property and which?:
I change the 'ChaptersInTheBook' with one of my querries when my combox selection changed. But this part is working. I'm sure about that.

Comment: So you mean you change the `ChaptersInTheBook` value in your view model, and that fires a PropertyChanged event, but `OnMaxValuePropertyChanged` in your UserControl is not called?

Comment: Yes, but if I start the aplication, and the `code`ChaptersInTheBook`code` has  an default value, the `code`MaxValue`code` change from the default value (which is 5) to the `code`ChaptersInTheBook`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I deleted from my user control `ctor` the `DataContext=this` settings and now it's working perfectly.